# Vectors of vectors string issue

Tags: c++

i'm in a situation with a declaration of `vector<vector<string>>`. On windows it's ok i can declare this in a struct like `vector<vector<string>>v={{"me","you"}}` but on a linux machine..only errors so i must declare it after the struct initialization but how because `mystruct.vec[0]={"me","you"}` gives me a segmentation fault. Any sugestions please?

Comment: Probably different compiler versions or compilers on windows and linux. Please specify the compilers you are using or (for the solution) just upgrade the linux box to the latest compiler.

Comment: This kind of initialization is relatively new - it's C++11. Not all compilers offer full support for the standard yet.

Comment: Well on windows i'm using codeblocks with mingw and latest gcc on linux.

Comment: @siloan: Then you forgot `-std=c++11` flag when building on linux.

Comment: @siloan the second is segfaulting because the vector is being intialized empty and you are assigning to the first element, which is past the end.

Comment: error: ‘>>’ should be ‘> >’ within a nested template argument list

Comment: @ChrisCondy `>>` is OK in C++11.

Comment: @juanchopanza He stated hes using 4.4.5 and according to http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/cxx0x_status.html does not fully suppot c++11

Comment: @ChrisCondy: Well, neither does 4.7.2. THe supported feature matrix claims it supports initializer lists. But that support was added in 4.4, so I wouldn't be too surprised if it didn't work exactly right in all cases, or if the standard library hadn't been updated to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program on gcc 4.7.2 works just fine:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

using ::std::vector;
using ::std::string;
using ::std::move;

vector<vector<string>> foo()
{
   vector<vector<string>>v={{"me","you"}};
   return move(v);
}

int main()
{
   using ::std::cout;

   cout << "{\n";
   for (auto &i: foo()) {
      cout << "   {\n";
      for (auto &o: i) {
         cout << "      \"" << o << "\",\n";
      }
      cout << "   },\n";
   }
   cout << "}\n";
   return 0;
}
```

It produces this output:

```
$ /tmp/a.out 
{
   {
      "me",
      "you",
   },
}
```

I think your problem is either an old compiler or that you have some other problem in some other place in your code.

I used this command line to compile:

```
$ g++ -std=gnu++0x -march=native -mtune=native -Ofast -Wall -Wextra vvstr.cpp
```

And my g++ gives this as a version:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.7.2 20121109 (Red Hat 4.7.2-8)
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

This page tells you which version of gcc has which C++ feature:

- http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Comment: @siloan - It looks like initializer lists were introduced in 4.4. Are you sure you're compiling with the `-std=gnu++0x` or `-std=c++0x` flags?

Comment: yes i'm compiling with that flag and for this 'std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> v = {{"me","you"}};' gives me a bounch of errors.

Comment: Then it looks like that support is semi-broken or the version of `::std::vector` in `libstdc++` (the C++ standard library) isn't set up to use it.

Comment: @siloan: gcc 4.4 was released in April 2009, so it is a 4 year old compiler.

Comment: Just installed ubuntu with a 4.7gcc and now it's fine with that flag, thank you guys for helping me out!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using GCC, them you need a version that supports this C++11 initialization feature, and then you need to tell the compiler to compile in C++11 mode by passing it the `-std=c++0x` flag (or `=std=c++11` for the 4.7 series). See [this demo](http://ideone.com/nXC1Xd), compiled with GCC 4.7.2:

```
#include <vector> 
#include <string>   
int main() 
{   
  std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> v = {{"me","you"}}; 
}
```